# Why does my tensor not show the array values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe, if I print the results of `tf.convert_to_tensor(numeric_features)` I should see the shape, data type and values of the array I created. I tried replicating the code and it works as intended.

However, in the neural network I'm trying to build, if I debug my code and print the tensor `x` (inside the custom loss function `constrained_mse`), I only see the shape and data type. The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
import numpy as np


# Hyperparameters
n_hidden_layers = 2 # Number of hidden layers.
n_units = 128 # Number of neurons of the hidden layers.
n_batch = 64 # Number of observations used per gradient update.
n_epochs = 30


# Create DataFrame (df) with random floats
np.random.seed(30)
call_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6000000, 6) * 100, 
                       columns=['Strike', "Time to Maturity", 
                                "Option_Average_Price", "RF Rate", 
                                "Sigma 20 Days Annualized", 
                                "Underlying Price"])
call_df = call_df.iloc[:10,:]

# Split call_df into random train and test subsets, for inputs (X) and output (y)
call_X_train, call_X_test, call_y_train, call_y_test = (train_test_split(
    call_df.drop(["Option_Average_Price"], axis = 1), 
    call_df.Option_Average_Price, test_size = 0.01))


# Create model using Keras' Functional API
def mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units):
    # Create input layer
    inputs = keras.Input(shape = (call_X_train.shape[1],))
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 1)(inputs)

    # Create hidden layers
    for _ in range(n_hidden_layers):
        x = hl(x, n_units)

    # Create output layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation = keras.activations.softplus)(x)

    # Actually create the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    
    return model


# Hidden layer generation function
def hl(tensor, n_units):
    hl_output = layers.Dense(n_units, 
                             activation = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=1))(tensor)
    return hl_output


# Custom loss function that is a MSE function plus three soft constraints
def constrained_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    
    mse = losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
    
    array = call_X_train.values
    model.run_eagerly = True
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(array, dtype="float32")
    print(x)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
            tape2.watch(x)
            y = model(x)
        
    grad_y = tape2.gradient(y, x)
    dy_dstrike = grad_y[0, 0]
    dy_dttm = grad_y[0, 1]
    
    grad_y2 = tape.gradient(y, x)
    d2y_dstrike2 = grad_y2[0, 0]
    
    loss = mse + dy_dstrike + dy_dttm + d2y_dstrike2

    return loss


model = mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units) 
model.compile(loss = constrained_mse, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),)
history = model.fit(call_X_train, call_y_train, batch_size = n_batch, 
                    epochs = n_epochs, validation_split = 0.01, verbose = 1)
```

The printed info of `x`:

```
<tf.Tensor 'loss_9/dense_29_loss/Const:0' shape=(9, 5) dtype=float64>
```

What I expected:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=1107, shape=(9, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[21.20808314, 26.72931683, 57.30885068, 91.73580787, 81.89759368],
       [51.81763468, 76.68551063,  8.97033828, 19.57712568, 99.41936843],
       [23.51804976, 23.89863719, 73.49525766, 68.83443831,  3.11307484],
       [16.31808924,  2.41547699, 26.4857379 , 33.93670564, 81.43695851],
       [33.52420797, 59.54382882, 34.62504239, 24.48318085, 69.7950165 ],
       [64.41435361, 38.07484896, 16.36507261, 96.26078137, 34.66618404],
       [80.74547159, 49.35616368, 36.51899844,  4.78308992, 26.41457864],
       [83.47150935, 36.698733  , 47.23791254, 38.61520885, 74.41370044],
       [99.17509923, 23.50578956, 40.66901016, 13.6234322 , 54.41362876]])>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried (in the "mlp3_call" method at the end) to set "model.run_eagerly = True"? I see that you enabled eager execution at the top (which is a requirement to see the tensor values) with the line "tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()" and I assume that I for some reason does not work on your model.

Comment: Tried it at the end of the code and before x. No change...

Comment: Could you maybe show the complete code where you printed x? I can not find the statement where you actually called your loss function and printed x which makes it quite hard to see why it does not work.

Comment: I don't print x in my code. What I did was debug the code, stop before x is calculated, calculate x and then print x. If I do this I can't see the values.

Now you may wonder, why do you want to see the values? Because I think that is what's making my code super slow. I've made posts about it but got no help so I'm narrowing down the scope to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: My problem with your code is that you say "when I pront x, then something does not happen" but you do not actually show how and where you print x, which is important though. So it would be good if you could just change your code in a way that you actually use the print(x) statement and the incorrect value is printed. And while you're at it, could you please add the "model.run_eagerly = True" statement as well, so that I can check whether you added it correctly? If you do this, I might be able to help, but with the information currently provided it is not possible.

Comment: I am editing the code in the post to suit what you asked.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and ran it without changes. For me, x was printed correctly in every iteration. There has to be something wrong this something besides your code. For your information, I am running python 3.8 with tensorflow 2.6.0, I am not sure whether a different tensorflow version could make a difference here, but there are no other potential reasons that I can think of.

Comment: One further note: You placed the "model.run_eagerly = True" line inside of your loss function, but you should have put it directly after defining your model and before your model.fit() call. Since you actually have an model.compile() call, it is even easier to include it in there, so just add the argument "run_eagerly=True" in your model.compile() call.

Comment: Oh yes I finally got it to print the values. Thanks. Now I have to understand the performance issue.